# Display Crystal Report On Balance Sheet Note Format

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I want to make a report on crystal report using ASP.Net MVC application. I am retrieving data from the database (MySql) stored procedure and load in the dataset. 
I want to show the data specific format which I attached, Report template snippet. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8K9j.jpg)

This is my query result which I load in the dataset: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ3mz.jpg)

This is my crystal report result show. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d79BG.jpg)

Note: Segment 1 and Segment 2 are N number of columns in the database for example if the database has only one Segment then Segment one with respective column () will show.

Comment: I think you need to have a try to show what you've done. There are lots of articles demonstrating using ASP.NET MVC with Crystal. Please post a  specific reproducible problem you are having

Comment: @PaulFarry thank you for your response but I am unable to find out any article which shows to make a report on my attached template. Attachment snippet end of the question.